# Is it better to pass more information in an intent to an activity or call the database in the other activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent

I'm making an application with Firebase where a User has to sign in to use the application. The MainActivity will only launch after the User has signed in, using `FirebaseAuth` and `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener`.

So in the Main Activity, I have all the information about the current User.

My question is, when navigating to other activities, is it better to pass more extras via Intents about the User (or any object) to `SecondActivity`, or is it better to read from the Firebase database in the `SecondActivity`?

(Both works fine for my app, but I'm thinking about good programming style / structure and thinking about resources, speed and performance)

Also worth mentioning, I want to keep in mind that almost all of the activities' screens / UI will be updated by the information about the current object, so I want the app to be as fast and responsive as possible. For some of the code I have in my project now, I have to use `Thread.sleep(x)`, to let the UI wait for the database to finish reading before updating the UI. This is what I'm currently using in my `Google Maps Activity`.

The PK of the User is the Gmail, used for signing in. Each User has several ArrayLists (that contains objects) that will grow larger when using the application, so eventually, a lot of information will be passed.

Take a look at the example code below, but don't bother too much with the details, it's just some code that I put in there now. The important thing is the general structure of how to retrieve and pass information in each activity:

**MainActivity:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("email", thisUser.getEmail());
startActivity(i);
```

**SecondActivity:**

```
private FirebaseDatabase Db;
private DatabaseReference destinationRef, userRef;
private String email;
private User thisUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.SecondActivity);

    email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");

    Db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    userRef = Db.getReference().child("Users");
    destinationRef = Db.getReference().child("Destinations");

    getInfoFromDb();
}

private void getInfoFromDb(){
    userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User u;
            for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren(){
                u = data.getValue(User.class);
                u.setUid(data.getKey());
                if(email.equalsIgnoreCase(u.getEmail())){
                    thisUser = u;
                    /* Update something else, based on this info */
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
    });
    destinationRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Destination d;
            for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                d = data.getValue(Destination.class);
                d.setUid(data.getKey());
                if(thisUser.getCurrentTrip().getDestinationName().equalsIgnoreCase(d.getDestinationName())){
                    /*Something else, update UI or whatever */
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
}
```

Here is another (shorter) example:

**MainActivity:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("email", thisUser.getEmail());
i.putExtra("rank", thisUser.getRank());
i.putExtra("points", thisUser.getPoints());
i.putExtra("someArray", thisUser.getSomeArray());
i.putStringArrayListExtra("somethingElse", thisUser.getSomeStringArrayList());
//  And let's say we put in a lot more information 
startActivity(i);
```

**SecondActivity**

```
thisEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
thisRank = getIntent().getStringExtra("rank");
thisEmail = getIntent().getIntExtra("points");
thisSomeArray = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("someArray");
thisArrayList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("somethingElse");
```

Which approach is better?

**1)** The first code example, where I read from the database in the `SecondActivity` to get info.

**2)** Send the whole thisUser-object (which can grow quite big, and serialization has to be used) from `MainActivity` to `SecondActivity`.

**3)** Pass more (can maybe be a lot) information from `MainActivity` with the Intents, to the other Activites.

Again, I'm thinking about good programming structure, practice, style and am concerned about speed, responsiveness and resources.

- Thanks!

Comment: Simply your code then no need to sync with server again and again try sharedpreferences(localstorage) once stored its retrieved anywhere in the application

Answer (score 0):

I would retrieve the data from the database, since you said it can be more information. So, its better to just retrieve the data from the database in the `SecondActivity`.

If you pass the data using `intent` it means you are sharing it between activities and not storing it.

Also lets say you want to do a query that involves more than one node (maybe two `nodes` under root(like a `join`) or nested `nodes`), you will have to retrieve the data from the database to be able to do that

Answer (score 0):

Think of testing.

In one case, you need your test framework to pass in all this extra data to test just the second method.  Coupling has been increased.  The method is less cohesive, since it can’t operate independently.

In the other case, the test framework doesn’t need to pass in the extra data, because the method retrieves the required information itself.  Coupling is decreased.  The method is more cohesive.

My $0.02

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very specific to the application being developed.

Passing data through intent or persisting it in DB is very subjective to what kind of data it is and what would be the action plan when you lose that data due to some reason.

**Pros & Cons** : Passing data in intent

Having data passed around in intent is good for transient or deduced data as it’s computed for taking some actions and shouldn’t be persisted or retrieved every time the activity is loaded.

Code will be more complicated as compared to DB approach as every time you traverse from one activity to another you have to add code to pass the intent or check the data passed or add new data in current activity. If system crashes you loose all data and state.

**Pros & Cons** : DB approach

having data in DB provides you a way to resume the state when there is crash or will act as checkpoint for future. It also means you have to maintain tables and code to handle them but it would be clean as the interfaces will be clean and defined. On same note, there can be multiple calls to save and retrieve data.

You also need to consider whether data is sensitive or not.

In nutshell, it’s purely upon your application needs and you have to identify what data is required for computation and what needs to be persisted and accordingly used mixed approach to achieve better performance with reliability.